# Automatic discount conditionated on checkout field: Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I want to apply a discount if a custom checkout field is filled.
That's the code i use to generate the discount:

```
function custom_wc_add_discount() {
    $0tax = WC()->cart->subtotal * -0.22;
    WC()->cart->add_fee( '0% tax', $0tax );
    }
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','custom_wc_add_discount' );
```

And I want to condition it with something like this:

```
if ( $_POST[billing_vat]){
```

---

**Edit:** I solved the condition problem creating a coupon like this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'apply_tax_coupon' );
function apply_tax_coupon() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $coupon_code = '0%val'; 
    $woocommerce->cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
    if ( $_POST[billing_vat]){
        $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code );
    }
    wc_print_notices();
}
```

But now in checkout page it doesn't show the discounted total.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You've told us what you want to do, but you haven't told us how you cannot. Just add the condition, and see if it works.

Comment: I tried to add the condition but it doesnt works. i'm not a developer and maybe i made some mistakes.

Comment: Okay. Please post the version which has the condition. If you made a mistake, someone can spot it.

Comment: If we see a mistake, we can also see and correct any misunderstanding. However, right now, we can only provide a link to (or repeat) JavaScript documentation, which you have access to just as easily.

Comment: I solved the condition problem creating a coupon like this:

Comment: add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 
    'apply_discounted_taxes' );
    function apply_discounted_taxes() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $coupon_code = '0%val'; 
    $woocommerce->cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
    if ( $_POST[billing_vat]){
        $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code );
    }
    wc_print_notices();
    }

Comment: You have some problems : you can't start php var with a number and you missed the quote arroung billing_vat in the condition

Comment: @Nicola What you are asking can NOT be done only with php but will need Javascript/jQuery (certainly Ajax), as it is not a server side event but a client side event. So it's going to be much more complicated and too broad for StackOverFlow without some related code.

Answer (score -1):

You have some problems :

- You can't start php var with a number
- you missed the quote arroung billing_vat in the condition

Try resolve this and we will see if there is other things to do.